# Meteor - Clicking anywhere in my entire app gives error "Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: /card/**randomID**

Tags: javascript, jquery, meteor

This error displays in chrome console every time I click, even when logged out, and I cannot figure out what is triggering it.

`Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: /card/nKHxPxoJzYvy6jLKa`

If I navigate to the route in the unrecognized expression, the page loads fine and the error stops displaying until I navigate to a different card route, then it starts appearing again but with the new card ID.

I'm using Iron Router.

Comment: Do you see a small link near the right border of the console on the same row with the error message? Click that link ...

Comment: I did, it points to a line in meteor core code. Maybe a package I added recently is causing this

Comment: It sounds like you're missing quotes somewhere. A filename that should probably be in a string is being interpreted as a Javascript statement.